# Latest packages available

Tags: apt

Due to [an accessibility bug in the latest versions of Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1245662) I will have to revert back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS when [12.10 is retired later this month](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). I see that [Ubuntu 12.04 came with Firefox 11.0](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu), LibreOffice 3.5, and other outdated (functionality-wise) software.

Though I have no problem compiling Firefox, LibreOffice, and other apps, I would like to know how could I find out what the *currently available* software versions are. **How could I check this before installing Ubuntu 12.04?** I *suppose* that at least Firefox would have been updated (due to Mozilla update policy), but I would like to check first before I install.

Is there some way to query the Canonical repos for the latest software versions available for 12.04 from my current 12.10 system? Would it be easier to check from some web interface on Launchpad? I'm looking for something similar to `aptitude show foobar`, but for which I could specify the distro version that the results would be returned for.

I *could* install a virtual machine to check, but I find that cumbersome and not really practical as a day-to-day solution should I ever need to do a similar check in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Links can help to see updates for Available Ubuntu Versions

**Ubuntu Packages** http://packages.ubuntu.com/

**Click For** [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/allpackages?format=txt.gz)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to check  the latest software package version available in the repositories for another  Ubuntu version via terminal commands (`apt-get` or `aptitude`).

Comment: Thank you Raj! How else would one go about getting the information, then?

Comment: But in gui way, it could be possible.Or run Ubuntu 12.04 on VM and check for the latest firefox package version available.

Comment: In the OP I did mention why I discount that method!